# How to NOT expose query methods in REST?

Tags: rest, jpa, spring-data-jpa

by default JPA DATA REST will expose query methods to /search/. I just wonder how to hide some of them.

For example, in my repository class:

```
public interface LeaseRepository extends CrudRepository<Lease, Long> {

    List<Lease> findByName(@Param("name") String name);

    List<Lease> findByIsActive(@Param("isActive") boolean isActive);
}
```

I would use findByName only internally, so how to disable it from being accessed in /search/findByName to others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just using annotation @RestResource:

```
@RestResource(exported = false)
List<Lease> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
```

[link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.hiding-repositories)